# How to generate bezier curve of image pixel into predefined shape

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, bezier

I have such type of image:

[image: collar]

and I have this texture:

[image]

I want to generate such curves that it should get fit in collar shape. I tried this snippet code but unable to do so. Help me

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");           // just some inits for demo
var img = new Image;
img.onload = slice;
img.src = "//i.stack.imgur.com/UvqUP.gif";

function slice() {
  var w = c.width = this.width;
  var h = c.height = this.height;
  var step = Math.PI*0.8/h;           // full circle / width of canvas
  var scale =250;                       // max displacement on y
  
  for(var x = 0; x < w; x++) {
    ctx.drawImage(this,
      x, 0, 1, h,                       // source line from image
      x, Math.sin(step*x)*scale, 1, h); // displaced line
  }
}
```

```css
canvas{
  transform:rotate(90deg)
}
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had implemented this kind of curve into collar structure.Some of the changes in the step and scale value and I got my solution.

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");           // just some inits for demo
var img = new Image;
img.onload = slice;
img.src = "//i.stack.imgur.com/UvqUP.gif";

function slice() {
  var w = c.width = this.width;
  var h = c.height = this.height;
  var step = Math.PI*2.3/w/2;        // full circle / width of canvas
  var scale =-180                    // max displacement on y
  
  for(var x = 0; x < w; x++) {
    ctx.drawImage(this,
      x, 0, 1, h,                       // source line from image
      x, Math.sin(step*x)*scale, 1, h); // displaced line
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```